# Send a Double type variable as an extra when sending an intent via adb shell

Tags: java, android, android-intent, adb

I wish to send a Double variable as an extra. It is easy to do with code but it seems that am can't do it.

Below is the am extra help, we can see that there are flags for `int`, `long` and even `float` but no `double`.

```
<INTENT> specifications include these flags and arguments:
    [-a <ACTION>] [-d <DATA_URI>] [-t <MIME_TYPE>]
    [-c <CATEGORY> [-c <CATEGORY>] ...]
    [-e|--es <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE> ...]
    [--esn <EXTRA_KEY> ...]
    [--ez <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_BOOLEAN_VALUE> ...]
    [--ei <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE> ...]
    [--el <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE> ...]
    [--ef <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE> ...]
    [--eu <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_URI_VALUE> ...]
    [--ecn <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_COMPONENT_NAME_VALUE>]
    [--eia <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_INT_VALUE...]]
    [--ela <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_LONG_VALUE...]]
    [--efa <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE...]]
    [-n <COMPONENT>] [-f <FLAGS>]
    [--grant-read-uri-permission] [--grant-write-uri-permission]
    [--debug-log-resolution] [--exclude-stopped-packages]
    [--include-stopped-packages]
    [--activity-brought-to-front] [--activity-clear-top]
    [--activity-clear-when-task-reset] [--activity-exclude-from-recents]
    [--activity-launched-from-history] [--activity-multiple-task]
    [--activity-no-animation] [--activity-no-history]
    [--activity-no-user-action] [--activity-previous-is-top]
    [--activity-reorder-to-front] [--activity-reset-task-if-needed]
    [--activity-single-top] [--activity-clear-task]
    [--activity-task-on-home]
    [--receiver-registered-only] [--receiver-replace-pending]
    [--selector]
    [<URI> | <PACKAGE> | <COMPONENT>]
```

Here is how i am trying to do it :

```
adb shell am startservice -a com.incorporateapps.fakegps.ENGAGE -e lat 5.1234 -e lng 1.333
```

I tried with all the flags available but no results achieved. The intent is sent successfully but the extras are not used because the app expect them to be double and probably get them with the `getDouble()`. I tried this with Tasker and this is working properly because i can add a "D" at the end to tell tasker it has to send a double.

Any idea ???

Comment: Found the solution:
adb shell am startservice -a com.incorporateapps.fakegps.ENGAGE 'intent:#Intent;action=com.incorporateapps.fakegps.ENGAGE;d.lat=48.832129;d.lng=2.302989;end'

Comment: it's easy to *find* a solution when it's been spelled out for you isn't it?

Comment: Nothing was spelled out for me, the answer in the "duplicate" question wasn't working at all. Thanks anyway